# Distinct combinations in a column over different partitions

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2022

Here is a simple table

| UserId | RoleId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

I am trying to find distinct combinations in RoleId column among different users. In this example I can see there are 3 users, but two distinct role combinations.

User 1 & 2 have [1,2,3,4] roles and user 3 has [1,2,3] roles. I can't get my head around if it is possible in T-Sql to return theses distinct combinations using PARTITION functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but:

```
SELECT DISTINCT STRING_AGG(roleid, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY roleid)
FROM t
GROUP BY userid;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wt3BAWOH)

Comment: That's perfect thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think with `PARTITION` it wold be a very hacky solution...

Based on the description this is what you need:

```
WITH AggregatedUserRoles AS (
    SELECT 
        UserId,
        STRING_AGG(RoleId, ',') AS RoleIds
    FROM UserRoles
    GROUP BY UserId
)
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(UserId, ',') AS UserIds,
    RoleIds
FROM AggregatedUserRoles
GROUP BY RoleIds;
```

with forced `PARTITION` it will look like somehow this (it gives errors ):

```
--with PARTITION
WITH AggregatedUserRoles AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        UserId,
        RoleId
    FROM UserRoles
),
RoleIdsByUser AS (
    SELECT
        UserId,
        STRING_AGG(RoleId, ',') OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY RoleId) AS RoleIds
    FROM AggregatedUserRoles
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    STRING_AGG(UserId, ',') OVER (PARTITION BY RoleIds ORDER BY UserId) AS UserIds,
    RoleIds
FROM RoleIdsByUser;
```

Examples in [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/J2TudL9y).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I was so hung up on PARTITION, didn't even think  about STRING_AGG